# Shoot Vs take the shot

Tags: usage

I was wondering if someone could tell me whether in the following self-made sentence I can substitute "took the shot" with just "shot" or it would sound unidiomatic or weird or something:

> - The Indian took aim at us with his bow and arrow and then **took the shot**.

Comment: Please  see [Q: Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer?s=0|1.6733) If you want the most from this website, I highly recommend you wait 2 or 3 days before selecting an answer. By selecting one as quickly as you do, you are hurting your chances to receive other answers, which you might judge to be even more helpful than the one you have currently selected.

Comment: @AlanCarmack thank you very much for letting me know this matter. You are absolutely right and I will observe this rule not only for getting more precise answers but also for helping other learners have more chances to receive more information if they come to similar questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it feels that you are using a term "took the shot" that comes from modern military usage (snipers, gun-sights, target lasers etc) and applying to older technology.

I'd be more inclined to say something more descriptive such as "and then let fly"

Be careful with use of the term "Indian"; I don't know where in the world you are setting this story but if you intend to refer to indigenous populations you can probably find a more appropriate term.

Comment: Thank you very much @djna for pointing to this matter; I exactly meant a redskin individual; respecting all dear Indian people who live in India. :)

Comment: @A-friend  On the preference of **(American) Indian** by American Indians: [source 1](http://www.nativetimes.com/index.php/life/commentary/11389-native-american-vs-american-indian-political-correctness-dishonors-traditional-chiefs-of-old), [source 2](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/roadshow/fts/bismarck_200504A16.html), [source 3](http://www.learnnc.org/lp/editions/nc-american-indians/5526), ad infinitum.

Comment: Alan, thanks for those references. I note that source 3 says that the authors try, where possible, to use more specific terms e.g. Sioux, and that would be my recommendation to A-friend for his story. I'm amused to see that the people organising the Nashville Powwow (which I have attended) are the Native American Indian Association of Tennessee.

Comment: SO based on my culture it's really hard to perceive these cultural gaps. I hope, sometimes, dear natives would give us foreigners a chance to miss these such sophisticated gaps.

Comment: A-friend, yes this stuff is tricky, not least because things change over time. No doubt I would be unaware of nuances in your culture too. The important thing is to be open to learning and adapting, and I think you're doing a fine job of that!

Comment: Thank you very much for kind and hopegiving words @djna; you are absolutely right. I have to try learn these gaps too (a language comes out from the heart of a culture which was born of a civilization)